# VBA: Extract column until empty, repeat in next sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, extract, worksheet

Dear Stack Overflow swarm.

In file "Prodcuts.xlmx" I have thousands of numerical values at column A at Worksheet "Contract1". Same file contains several other similar Worksheets with names "Contract2" and so forth. The number of rows changes in each worksheet and may change in same worksheet over time, but they are always followed by empty row. Number of worksheets is static

I need to collect the information from these worksheets to second file to a single worksheet, lets call it "Productlist" in a format where Column A contains Worksheet name repeated, and Column B the numerical values.

I would prefer a extraction loop that simply copies this information, to avoid multiple check's for possible changes.

I can not use select column for copying source, as after empty cells, comes additional set of data which is not required.

General idea is

Get WS1 Column A content, until empty row, copy to "Productlist" column B

Get WS1 WS Name, copy to "Produclist" column A, repeat until Column B has no value (or Column B +1 row has no value, to avoid 1 extra row of WS name)

Add 2 empty rows

Repeat for WS2, until WSn does not exist (or match count).

Comment: I went wrongly towards rowcounter usage and checks if something has been added to the "Contract1", then realizing I have to counter check if something has been removed, and that I could not upkeep the format structure after several iterations of the loop with different worksheets without excessive work.

I'm completely beyond my abilities when referring to another file, and I do not know how to loop over different worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered soemthing similiar in the other post, modified it bit. Customized for your case

```
Sub testing()
Dim resultWs As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dataArray As Variant
Dim height As Long
Dim currentHeight As Long
Dim wsName As String
Set resultWs = Worksheets("Productlist")
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If InStr(ws.Name, "Contract") Then
        With ws
            wsName = .Name
            height = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row 'look til empty row
            If height > 1048575 Then
                height = 1
            End If

            ReDim dataArray(1 To height, 1 To 1)
            dataArray = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(height, 1)).Value

        End With

        With resultWs
            currentHeight = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
                currentHeight = 0
            End If
            If VarType(dataArray) <> vbDouble Then
                .Range(.Cells(currentHeight + 1, 1), .Cells(currentHeight + UBound(dataArray, 1), 1)).Value = wsName
                .Range(.Cells(currentHeight + 1, 2), .Cells(currentHeight + UBound(dataArray, 1), 2)).Value = dataArray
            Else
                .Cells(currentHeight + 1, 1).Value = wsName
                .Cells(currentHeight + 1, 2).Value = dataArray
            End If

        End With
    End If

Next ws

End Sub
```